# How to change the text "Sign up to get notified when this product is back in stock" in magento to a button

Tags: magento

I want the text "Sign up to get notified when this product is back in stock" to be changed into a button on the site, how do I change the design. Im using magento as a backend for the website.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can change lable from

```
YOUR_PACKAGE_NAME\YOUR_NAME\template\productalert\product\view.phtml
```

if this file not found then you can find from

```
base\default\template\productalert\product\view.phtml
```

in

```
<a href="<?php echo $this->escapeHtml($this->getSignupUrl()) ?>" title="<?php echo $this->escapeHtml($this->__($this->getSignupLabel())); ?>"><?php echo "YOUR_LABEL" ?></a>
```

**change your text from YOUR_LABEl**